# Как создать в своей теме подобные настройки?

Tags: wordpress

Как мне в своей теме при разработке реализовать подобные настройки? Это делается через фреймворк какой-то или с нуля самому делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это точно реализуется силами WordPress, никаких плагинов или фреймворков использовать не нужно. [Это то, что вы искали](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress предоставляет функции для реализации собственных настроек темы или плагинов. Вот простейший работающий пример из одного проекта:

```
//Страница настроек
function test_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2 id="title"><?php echo('Настройки сайта test'); //your admin panel title ?></h2>

        <form action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            settings_fields( 'test_settings' ); // скрытые защитные поля
            do_settings_sections ('test-settings');  // секции с настройками (опциями)
            submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Добавление страницы настроек в меню
function add_settings_page() {
    add_menu_page( 'Настройки сайта test', 'Настройки сайта test', 'administrator', 'test-settings', 'test_settings_page', 'dashicons-carrot');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_settings_page' );

/**
 * Регистрируем настройки.
 * Настройки будут храниться в массиве, а не одна настройка = одна опция.
 */
function test_settings(){
    // параметры: $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback
    register_setting( 'test_settings', 'test_settings', 'sanitize_callback' );

    // параметры: $id, $title, $callback, $page
    add_settings_section( 'section_notice', 'Рассылка уведомлений об обновлении', '', 'test-settings' );

    // параметры: $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args
    add_settings_field('test_field0', 'Тема сообщения', 'fill_field0', 'test-settings', 'section_notice' );
    add_settings_field('test_field1', 'Шаблон сообщения', 'fill_field1', 'test-settings', 'section_notice' );
    add_settings_field('test_field2', 'Копия администратору', 'fill_field2', 'test-settings', 'section_notice' );

    $val = get_option('test_settings');
    if (empty($val)) { // default values
        $val['email_subject'] = 'Проект был обновлен';
        $val['email_template'] = '<p>На сайте был обновлен проект, который Вы спонсировали:</p><p>Спасибо за помощь и поддержку!</p><p>С уважением,<br> Администрация сайта.</p><p></p>';
        $val['admin_copy'] = false;
        update_option( 'test_settings', $val);
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'test_settings');

// Заполняем опцию 0
function fill_field0(){
    $val = get_option('test_settings');
    $val = $val['email_subject'];
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="test_settings[email_subject]" value="<?php echo strip_tags( $val ) ?>" class="regular-text ltr" />
    <?php
}

// Заполняем опцию 1
function fill_field1(){
    $val = get_option('test_settings');
    $val = $val['email_template'];
    ?>
    <p>Заполните этот шаблон кодом html.</p>
    <textarea name="test_settings[email_template]" rows="10" cols="50" class="large-text code"><?php echo wp_kses( $val, 'post' ) ?></textarea>
    <?php
}

// Заполняем опцию 2
function fill_field2(){
    $val = get_option('test_settings');
    $val = $val['admin_copy'];
    ?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test_settings[admin_copy]" value="1" <?php checked( 1, $val ) ?> /> Отправлять</label>
    <?php
}

// Валидация ввода
function sanitize_callback( $options ){
    foreach( $options as $name => & $val ){
        if( $name == 'email_subject' )
            $val = strip_tags( $val );

        if( $name == 'email_template' )
            $val = wp_kses( $val, 'post' );

        if( $name == 'admin_copy' )
            $val = intval( $val );
    }
    return $options;
}
```

После добавления этого кода в functions.php вашей темы вы получите следующую страницу настроек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная инструкция на русском языке доступна [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Это делается через фреймворк какой-то или с нуля самому делать?

Для такого есть несколько фреймворков. В данном случае насколько я вижу это похоже [Redux](http://reduxframework.com/).

Однако согласно последним рекомендациям ВП стоит использовать не подобное, а Theme Customization API, См https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Comment: да, redux, как оказалось там. А чем лучше API? Ведь так много тем на themeforest с фреймворками идут.

Comment: АПИ уже лучше тем что это родное и значит будет работать всегда. А [на темофоресте и тп помойках темы существуют прежде всего для продаж](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/источник-тем-маркеты-или-официальный/), а не для реального использования. Но это никак не связано с тем, на чём они сделаны - 99% юзеров не знает что внутри и зачем (АПИ кастомайзера - это относительно новое, а продаются старые технологии). Продаётся КАРТИНКА а не возможности и способы настроек. Внутри же полное глючное говно, в большинстве случаев без конструктора (вижуалкомпозер и тп) совершено бесполезное.