# Редактирование сущностей из разных материалов

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть корпоративный сайт на WordPress.

Есть материалы в которых в которых есть общие данные, например глубина погружения прибора.

После доработки глубина изменяется и это всё надо оперативно внести во все материалы с приборами.

Как изначально решить вопрос с редактированием материалов и сапортом сайта так, что бы это занимало максимально мало времени?

Какие плагины мне надо смотреть?

Есть ли подобные патерны редактирования материалов?

Comment: А как эти материалы хранятся и выводятся сейчас?

Comment: сейчас просто в каждый материал заходит человек ищет где это прописано было и простейшая редакция 10 материалов забирает не меньше часа. по этому ищем решение для реорганизации сайта.

Comment: В WordPress можно создавать свои настройки темы - по сути поля с произвольными значениями. Посмотрите мои ответы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699277/220220 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220 Вывести материалы в записи проще всего шорткодом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716384/220220